# How To Pass Value from InputTextArea To InputField

Tags: visualforce, javascript, custom-field, html

**Scenari**o : I am doing with VFP. VFP has custom multiple record selection lookup. So When I Check records in multiple record selection lookup one inputtextarea element is capturing those records as comma seperated values.

**My Requirement** : So, now I want to pass those captured values in an InputTextArea to a Field(custom object field with datatype TextArea) While Saving the record. How do I do that?

for example:

```
<apex:inputtextarea id="texttocaptureonclientside" value="{!controllerValue}"/>
```

I tried with javascript like below. But not working because some other js in vfp is blocking this

```
<apex:commandbutton value="save" action="{!save}" onclick="loadToFielad();"/>

<apex:inputtextarea id="texttocaptureonclientside" value="{!controllerValue}"/>
<apex:inputHidden id="inputhiddenfield" value="{!Object__c.Captured_Members__c}"/>

<script>
function loadToField(){
      var hiddenfield = document.getElementById('pageid:mainFormid:pgBId:inputhiddenfield');
      hiddenfield.value = document.getElementById('texttocaptureonclientside').value;

    }
 </script>
```

Comment: Can't you set that in the `save` action at the controller level?

Comment: Can't you just change merge variable in the inputTextArea from `inputtextarea` to `{!Object__c.Captured_Members__c}`?

Comment: And if you trying to set a value to the text area - this HTML tag don't have any value. You should set it to the text: `hiddenfield.text`

Comment: @highfive -Thanks for your suggestion. I tried with controller save method and it is working.